# Multiple Column Check in Linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

Kindly guide in writing the below sql query in linq

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Item.Id AS ItemId, Item.CatId, [Case].Id AS CaseId
    FROM [Item] WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Case] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Case].Id = Item.CaseId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Cust] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Case].CustId1 = Cust.Id OR 
       [Case].CustId2 = Cust.Id
```

I could not understand how include CustId1 and CustId2 in the join.

Below is my linq without CustId2:

```
 var query = (from i in db.Item
              join c in db.Case on i.CaseId equals c.Id
              into joined
              from c in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join cus in db.Cust on c.CustId1 equals cus.Id
              into cust

              from cus in cust.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  Item=i,
                  Case = c,
                  Category = ct,
                  Pro = pr,
                  ZCatClass =zcc,
                  ZCatTyp = cct,
                  cust = cus
              }).OrderByDescending(d => d.Item.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Which ORM is this and which navigation properties have you got?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from i in Items
    from c in Cases.Where(z => z.Id == i.CaseId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from cust in Custs.Where(z => z.Id == c.CustId1 || z.Id == c.CustId2).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        ...
    }).OrderByDescending(z => z.Item.Id).ToList();
```